# Form group async validator function not getting called

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I need to implement async validation dependent on multiple form fields, so I placed the validation on `FormGroup`. But the validation function is not getting called. Surely am missing something.

```
heroForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4),
        forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)
      ]),
      'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo, {        
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),
      'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
    }, null,this.validate.bind(this));
  }

  validate(
    ctrl: FormGroup
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    console.log(ctrl)
    return this.heroesService.isAlterEgoTaken(ctrl.controls.alterEgo.value).pipe(
      map(isTaken => { 
        console.log(isTaken);
        return (isTaken ? { uniqueAlterEgo: true } : null)
        }),
      catchError(() => null)
    );
  }
```

Created a demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtqhqi

Comment: tried your demo, validate function is correctly called. Why do you think it is not called?

Comment: @Ludevik Doesn't get called when I make any change in `alterEgo` field. Pls recheck.

Comment: `alterEgo` has `updateOn: 'blur'` specified. try writing something in and then blur that input.

Comment: Doesn't work, although removing `updateOn:'blur'` from it works. So, seems not using it right.

Comment: `updateOn: 'blur'` works for me, but only when i first trigger the validator by typing in other inputs. When i first navigate to the page and blur that input, then it doesn't work. strange

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Async validators are fired only when all sync validators return null. So remove all form errors and then the async validator will be called.

Don't forget that you have `updateOn: 'blur'` specified for that input, so you have to blur the input to trigger validation.

Comment: "Async validators are fired only when all sync validators return null". That was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck on this silly thing for hours, haha.